# Setting document field value using Firestore Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this function that updates a user's feed after following another user by getting the post IDs of that user's posts and then adding them to a 'user-feed' in the users document. It worked fine until I added the timestamp field in. What I'm trying to do is to add the timestamp from each post to the document that is being created in the user-feed, so that I can get the feed posts by ordering it by timestamp.

Error I'm getting:

> Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "timestamp"). If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`.

```
 exports.updateUserFeedAfterFollow = functions.firestore.document('/following/{currentUid}/user-following/{uid}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const currentUid = context.params.currentUid;
    const uid = context.params.uid;
    const db = admin.firestore();
    functions.logger.log('Function called..')

    return db.collection('posts').where('ownerUid', '==', uid).get().then((snapshot) => {
        functions.logger.log('Fetched posts..')
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => { 
            const postId = doc.id;
              const timestamp = doc.timestamp;
            functions.logger.log('PostID:', postId)
            const writeResult = db.collection('users').doc(currentUid).collection('user-feed').doc(postId);
            writeResult.set({timestamp: timestamp});
        });
        return null;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        functions.logger.log(err);
      });
  });
```

I tried to add the timestamp of each post to the document that was created. It doesn't run and gives an error

Comment: What's the error you get? Please edit your question to include this information (there's a small `edit` link under it for this purpose). In future posts, please include such information right away.

Comment: Hi Frank, sorry I thought it was a syntax issue. I added the error to the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is coming from this line:

```
        writeResult.set({timestamp: timestamp});
```

It's saying that the value of `timestamp` is `undefined`, which is not valid in Firestore.  In fact, `timestamp` is always going to be undefined since you're not accessing document fields correctly.  To get an object with all the key/value pairs of fields, you should call [data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot.md#documentsnapshotdata) on the DocumentSnapshot instead:

```
const data = doc.data();
const timestamp = data.timestamp;
```

Since we can't see the results of the query, nor the contents of the document from the query, we can't tell you anything more that will help.

Also you should make sure you wait for the promise returned by `set` to resolve before returning from the function.  Otherwise, Cloud Functions might terminate your code before it completes.

Comment: Is there a a different syntax I use use when timestamps are involved ? timestamp field in post is 
March 22, 2024 at 9:39:48 PM UTC.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you log the value in the code and see for yourself?  The error message says the value is undefined, and it's almost certainly not wrong about that.  It's not about syntax, it's about the actual data you're trying to write.

Comment: I logged the timestamp and it does say undefined.. But the post has timestamp field in it. (related to the postID which is shown in the log as it prints it).

Comment: We can't see your data or know how you're observing this timestamp otherwise, so we can only assume that the error message is correct.  It looks like you're not calling `data()` on the snapshot to get the actual document fields.  See the revised answer.

Comment: I logged doc, doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot {
  _fieldsProto: {
    
    caption: { stringValue: 'Saw this', valueType: 'stringValue' },
    didLike: { booleanValue: false, valueType: 'booleanValue' },
    timestamp: { timestampValue: [Object], valueType: 'timestampValue' },
    likes: { integerValue: '0', valueType: 'integerValue' }
  },

Comment: You need to call data() on the snapshot to get at the actual document data.

Comment: Thanks. I called data on doc and now it works!